# Type casting of class variables in PHP/Symfony/Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, symfony1, types, casting

Whenever I need to use the intelligence of Netbeans to show properties/methods, I explicitly declare a new object and then re-reference it. Something like..

```
    $moo = new Cow();
    $moo = Cow::getById(1);
    $hasMilk = $moo->hasMilk();
```

Is there a way I can avoid this by type-casting the variable when getting it?
Or atleast a hack to fool Netbeans?

Thanks!

PS: the main reason of solving this is something if I forget to comment line 1, and when obj is not found, it works with a fresh object! :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$moo = Cow::getById(1); /* @var $moo Cow */
```

this will tell netbeans that $moo is an object of type Cow

Comment: I use this a lot. Note that `/**` doesn't work. Silly, but true.

Comment: @Coronatus Indeed, I found that quite strange, part because `/**` marks the beginning of a docblock, part because my previous editor (phped) used that.

Comment: Or you can add a DocBlock to the method getById() on Cow with @return stating the type, and Netbeans will know when you use getById() that $moo is a Cow.

Answer (score 1):

Type `vdoc` and press tab. In the comment that appears put name of the class.

Comment: Thanks Mchl for the Shortcut. What is the shortcut to bring out the template for a method?

Comment: Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code templates
There you can review existing and add your own templates.